# get next row after specific row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to figure out a way to reliably get the next row after another. I have the following schema:

```
id varchar(36),
received_at timestamp(6) with time zone
```

This query works most of the time

```
SELECT *
FROM receipt_emails
WHERE id > '50e8340a-2db5-42c2-add8-81ba732e9123'
ORDER BY RECEIVED_AT ASC
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

But sometimes it doesn't and I don't know why. I have the following 2 rows in the database now.

```
id                                   | received_at
50e8340a-2db5-42c2-add8-81ba732e9123 | "2015-08-04 05:16:13.000000"
4744eb81-9233-462a-8ee6-43302ef85671 | "2015-08-04 05:17:53.000000"
```

Executing the above query returns zero results. I would expect to get the row with the id of `4744eb81-9233-462a-8ee6-43302ef85671`. I have a feeling it has to do with the `where` portion of the query not doing what I'm intending.

Comment: Why would you expect to get `4744...` when you asked for rows greater than `50e8...`?

Comment: Ditto to @Blorgbeard.  String comparisons work fine, but your two string ids are not in sequence, so the where id > ... clause takes the second row out of commission.  You need to test on received_at > ...

Comment: In the ASCII collating sequence of a character field, the ID starting with the '4' comes BEFORE the ID that starts with the '5' that you are asking for, thus you get zero results.

Comment: I think perhaps the thing you're missing is that the `order by` does not modify the behaviour of `>` in the where-clause. You can think of it like "first get the rows where ID > xxx, then order those rows by yyy". Not "Get the rows after the one with ID xxx when ordering by yyy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT re.*
FROM receipt_emails re
WHERE received_at > (SELECT received_at
                     FROM receipt_emails re2
                     WHERE re2.id = '50e8340a-2db5-42c2-add8-81ba732e9123'
                    )
ORDER BY RECEIVED_AT ASC
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

The comparison should be to the timestamp, not the id.